# Set font size to header's elements after applied a fomatter to multiple columns in formattable

Tags: r, formattable

With code below, I'm able to customize column `mpg` and `disp`'s format:

```
library(formattable)
data(mtcars)

df <- mtcars

f1 <- formatter("span", style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(x > 0, red, blue), "font-size:20px"))
f2 <- formatter("span", style = x ~ style("font-size:20px"))

formattable(df, list(
  `mpg` = f1,
  `disp` = f2
  ))
```

[image]
Based what I have done above, I would like to set font size for header's elements by applying `f2` to header:

```
formattable(df, list(
  `mpg` = f1,
  `disp` = f2,
  names(df) <- f2(names(df))
  ))
```

But as you may notice, the effect for `mpg` and `disp` have disappeared, any ideas to deal with this issue? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by the code below:

```
library(formattable)
data(mtcars)

df <- mtcars

f1 <- formatter("span", style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(x > 0, red, blue), "font-size:20px"))
f2 <- formatter("span", style = x ~ style("font-size:20px"))

df$mpg <- f1(df$mpg) 
df$disp <- f2(df$disp) 
names(df) <- f2(names(df))
formattable(df)
```

Out:

[image]